# JavaFx InvocationTargetExeption at runtime

Tags: java, javafx

I am Trying to run a Othello framework built with javaFx. But when i run the program i get the following Exception output message:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.web.NGWebView (in unnamed module @0x4161954e) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGGroup (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.sg.prism to unnamed module @0x4161954e
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at com.eudycontreras.othello.views.GameAboutView$Link.<init>(GameAboutView.java:318)
    at com.eudycontreras.othello.views.GameAboutView.getFields(GameAboutView.java:103)
    at com.eudycontreras.othello.views.GameAboutView.initialize(GameAboutView.java:129)
    at com.eudycontreras.othello.views.GameAboutView.initialize(GameAboutView.java:115)
    at com.eudycontreras.othello.application.OthelloGameView.initialize(OthelloGameView.java:146)
    at com.eudycontreras.othello.application.Othello.<init>(Othello.java:73)
    at main.AgentManager.start(AgentManager.java:55)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:389)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application main.AgentManager
```

Why does this happen and how can i fix it?
The framework i am using can be found on this github: https://github.com/EudyContreras/Othello-Framework

Here is the class where the program will run from:

```
package main;

import com.eudycontreras.othello.application.Othello;
import com.eudycontreras.othello.enumerations.BoardCellState;
import com.eudycontreras.othello.enumerations.PlayerTurn;
import com.eudycontreras.othello.models.GameBoardCell;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * <H2>Created by</h2> Eudy Contreras
 * <h4> Mozilla Public License 2.0 </h4>
 * Licensed under the Mozilla Public License 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * <a href="https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/MPL/2.0/">visit Mozilla Public Lincense Version 2.0</a>
 * <H2>Class description</H2>
 * Class which represents an AI agent which will produce a move
 * Feel free to take a good look at the agent controller for additional
 * helper methods, examples and methods for creating more complex AI agents.
 * 
 * Feel also free to refer to the threading package for multi-threading and timer helpers
 * 
 * <pre>
 *  Execute a task on a separate thread
 * 
 *  ThreadManager.execute(()->{
 *   Thing to do here
 *  });
 *              
 *  Execute a task and perform an action upon completion
 *              
 *  ThreadManager.execute(
 *   (success)-> {
 *       Task to perform 
 *   },
 *   ()-> {
 *       Thing to do upon completion
 *   });
 *</pre>
 * 
 * @author Eudy Contreras
 *
 */
public class AgentManager extends Application{
    

    /**
     * Application start method: Choose the agent
     * you wish to use and run the program
     */
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        new Othello(primaryStage, new ExampleAgentOne("Agent A"), new ExampleAgentTwo("Agent B"));
        //new Othello(primaryStage, new ExampleAgentB());
        //new Othello(primaryStage, new ExampleAgentC());
        //new Othello(primaryStage, new ExampleAgentD());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    public static void printBoard(GameBoardCell[][] cells) {
        printBoard(cells, false);
    }
    
    public static void printBoard(GameBoardCell[][] cells, boolean print) {
        
        if(!print){
            return;
        }
        
        System.out.println();
        
        System.out.print(" ");
        for (int row = 0; row < cells.length; row++) {
            System.out.print("   "+row);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int row = 0; row < cells.length; row++) {

            System.out.println("  ---------------------------------");

            System.out.print(row + " |");

            for (int col = 0; col < cells[row].length; col++) {

                if (cells[col][row].getCellState() != BoardCellState.EMPTY) {
                    System.out.print(" " + cells[col][row] + " |");
                } else {
                    System.out.print(" " + " " + " |");
                }
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("  ---------------------------------");
        
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like this has something to do with ModuleInfo.Java. Look up `module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.sg.prism to unnamed module`

Comment: Try using Java 8 which includes JavaFX and is not modular.

Comment: Simply include `javafx.web` in your `--add-modules` argument, _or_ make your code modular, add a `requires javafx.web` directive to your module-info descriptor and launch your code with `--module`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have JavaFX on the classpath instead of the module path.

I suggest using a JDK distribution that includes JavaFX to simplify this.  Try one from BellSoft or Azul that is a "full" or "fx" version.